# Accessing phones storage to upload files and photos in an android app developed using webview

Tags: android-studio, android-webview, user-permissions, file-access

I have converted a website to an app using webview where I need to access the images and files from the phone's storage. I tried adding READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but it doesn't work

here is my MainActivity.java code

```
package xyz.myassessment.udhyog;<br>
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;<br>
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;<br>
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;<br>
import android.os.Build;<br>
import android.os.Bundle;<br>
import android.util.Log;<br>
import android.webkit.WebSettings;<br>
import android.webkit.WebView;<br>
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;<br>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {<br>
//    public static final Object TAG = ;<br>
    private WebView mywebview;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.udhyog.xyz/");
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        isStoragePermissionGranted();
    }
    @Override
    public  void  onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebview.canGoBack())
        {
            mywebview.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE,"Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
            //resume tasks needing this permission
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file is here

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What part does not work? What API level are you using to test your code?

Comment: Another question is whether you actually need direct storage access or if you can use the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: The permission box is coming and it is asking for permissions ,I have given allow but when I press the upload button present using webview,cannot access the files